# NOT EQUAL TO not working in javascript

Tags: javascript

When I am using this:

```
case "vic":
    if ((bPostcodeSubstring == 3) || (bPostcodeSubstring == 8)){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        errMsg += "Enter A Valid Postcode.";
        result = false;             
    }
break;
```

It is working fine. But when I am using this:

```
case "vic":
    if ((bPostcodeSubstring != 3) || (bPostcodeSubstring != 8)){
        errMsg += "Enter A Valid Postcode.";
        result = false;             
    }
break;
```

It is not working at all. What's the problem?

Answer (score 6):

```
!((bPostcodeSubstring == 3) || (bPostcodeSubstring == 8))
```

is NOT same as

```
(bPostcodeSubstring != 3) || (bPostcodeSubstring != 8)
```

it should be

```
(bPostcodeSubstring != 3) && (bPostcodeSubstring != 8)
```

demorgan's law

Answer (score 1):

If you want both 3 and 8 unacceptable for this variable, then you have to use `&&`.

```
if ((bPostcodeSubstring != 3) && (bPostcodeSubstring != 8)){
    errMsg += "Enter A Valid Postcode.";
    result = false;             
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `or` is resolving always to `true`, consider if bPostcodeSubstring is 3 then first condition fails but second gives true. If you want to exclude 3 and 8 then use not outside of both or condition

```
if (!(bPostcodeSubstring == 3 || bPostcodeSubstring == 8)){
```

OR use and `&&` instead of `||` If you want to exclude 3 and 8 then use not outside of both or condition

```
if ((bPostcodeSubstring != 3) && (bPostcodeSubstring != 8)){
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `&&` insead of `||` in your second `if`.

Indeed, the opposite of :

```
(bPostcodeSubstring == 3) || (bPostcodeSubstring == 8)
```

Is :

```
(bPostcodeSubstring != 3) && (bPostcodeSubstring != 8)
```